# Joomla JEditor getcontent method?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

```
 echo $jsc = $editor->getContent("myEditorField");
```

and getcontent

```
 * Get the editor contents
 *
 * @param   string  $editor The name of the editor control
 *
 * @return  string
 */
public function getContent($editor)
{
    $this->_loadEditor();

    $args['name'] = $editor;
    $args['event'] = 'onGetContent';

    $return = '';
    $results[] = $this->_editor->update($args);

    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        if (trim($result)) {
            $return .= $result;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

how above piece of code is returning this string

```
WFEditor.getContent('myEditorField')
```

Comment: Hope this will help you,http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aUsing_the_editor_in_a_component

Comment: Jobin can you help me find out where _editor->update($args) function is. i already searched out plugin files.